# OOP approach for the Triangle Check scenario

Tags: c#, linq, oop, enums

Recently I had a practical test for Software developer position , in that test they asked following question.

> Write me a function that receives three integer inputs for the lengths
>   of the sides of a triangle and returns one of four values to determine
>   the triangle type (1=scalene, 2=isosceles, 3=equilateral, 4=error)

Also they asked to use `enums` and `OOP` approach for this solution,

but without `OOP` approach I built that on following way

```
using System;
using System.Linq;

namespace triangleSolution
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int[] values = new int[3];

            for (int i = 1; i <= 3; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Please enter side " + i +" value");  
                values[i - 1] = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            }

          Console.WriteLine(GetTriangleType(values[0], values[1], values[2]));
          Console.WriteLine();
        }

        public enum TriangleType
        {
            Scalene = 1, // no two sides are the same length
            Isosceles = 2, // two sides are the same length and one differs
            Equilateral = 3, // all sides are the same length
            Error = 4 // inputs can't produce a triangle
        }

        public static TriangleType GetTriangleType(int a, int b, int c)
        {
            // There should also be a side length check
            if (a <= 0 || b <= 0 || c <= 0)
            {
                return TriangleType.Error;
            }

            if (a == b && a == c) // These could also be their own methods
            {
                return TriangleType.Equilateral;
            }
            else if (a == b || a == c || b == c)
            {
                return TriangleType.Isosceles;
            }
            else
            {
                return TriangleType.Scalene;
            }       

        }           

    }
}
```

I wish to extend above solution in OOP way though I failed that interview :)

Comment: For a simple half-mathematical question like this, what would there be an OOP way? Everything looks ok. Maybe they wanted you to return an Interger instead of an enum

Comment: @lokusking actually they emphasized to build a solution in OOP way , so I'm glad to study it

Comment: Whoever worded that question probably had no idea what OOP is supposed to be used for. A single(!) function doesn't warrant an entire class.

Comment: @ManfredRadlwimmer I thought I'm the only guy confused after saw that question :)

Answer (score 2):

There are many ways to do this (based on the vague description)

e.g.: use `a,b,c` in a class `Triangle` that has a property `TriangleType`

But I have to say, the wording

> Write me a function that ...

Is very misleading if OOP was what they were after.

```
public enum TriangleType
{
    Scalene = 1, // no two sides are the same length
    Isosceles = 2, // two sides are the same length and one differs
    Equilateral = 3, // all sides are the same length
    Error = 4 // inputs can't produce a triangle
}

public class Triangle
{
    public TriangleType TriangleType {get; private set;}
    public int SideA {get; private set;}
    public int SideB {get; private set;}
    public int SideC {get; private set;}

    public Triangle(int a, int b, int c)
    {
        SideA = a;
        SideB = b;
        SideC = c;
        TriangleType = GetTryangleType(a,b,c);
    }

    public static TriangleType GetTriangleType(int a, int b, int c)
    {
        // There should also be a side length check
        if (a <= 0 || b <= 0 || c <= 0)
        {
            return TriangleType.Error;
        }

        if (a == b && a == c) // These could also be their own methods
        {
            return TriangleType.Equilateral;
        }
        else if (a == b || a == c || b == c)
        {
            return TriangleType.Isosceles;
        }
        else
        {
            return TriangleType.Scalene;
        }       
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int[] values = new int[3];

    for (int i = 1; i <= 3; i++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Please enter side " + i +" value");  
        values[i - 1] = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    }

    Triangle triangle = new Triangle(values[0], values[1], values[2]);

    Console.WriteLine(triangle.TriangleType);
    Console.WriteLine();
}
```

Comment: But honestly, isnt that a bit overkill for the requested task?

Comment: @lokusking Absolutely! The function itself works and fits the wording of the task. If they wanted to see some OOP skills they should have used a different task.

Comment: @ManfredRadlwimmer your solution seems good to study , Ill go through this.  many thanks

Answer (score 1):

You could use a triangle class, something like this

```
 public class Triangle
 {
      private int[] sideLength;

      public Triangle(int side1, int side2, int side3)
      {
          sideLength = new int[3];
          sideLength[0] = side1;
          sideLength[1] = side2;
          sideLength[2] = side3;
      }

      public TriangleType GetTriangleType()
      {
           //Your code here ;)
      }

 }
```

Comment: This is the simplest "OOP" solution - a noun for a class, a constructor that takes dependencies, and a no-argument method that does the work.